# Creating a knowledge base in dialogflow with java API

Tags: dialogflow-es

I need to create a knowledge base and add some question/answer data there. I  went through this example https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-java-client-v2/blob/master/samples/src/main/java/com/example/dialogflow/KnowledgebaseManagement.java  but that apparently just creates an empty knowledge base.

Tried digging through the (very poor) documentation available but found no way to make it actually do something useful.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-java-client-v2/blob/master/samples/src/main/java/com/example/dialogflow/DocumentManagement.java

Need to jump through these hoops